# Get Token from Azure AC B2C

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I tried to get a token from Azure AD B2C but I've got this message:

> AADSTS90002: Tenant not found. This may happen if there are no active
>   subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription
>   administrator

Comment: Can you please paste the endpoint URL that you are calling to acquire the token?

Comment: finally I've got an token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TENANT}}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Note, you must include the policy name in either the URL path or query, in order to acquire tokens for use with Azure AD B2C-registered apps.

Comment: Yep, for get a token I need registred my Enterprise app in Azure AD and get my client_id(applicationId) and mi client_secret.